# DocuSign Sharepoint-on-Premise 2013 Connector

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, docusignapi

Does anyone have any experience using the DocuSign Connector with SharePoint-On-Premise 2013?

We have set up the connector but was prompted the following message:

[image]

My SharePoint user has an email tied to my DocuSign administrator email, does anyone have any potential solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking the error above means we didn't find an email address in the SharePoint profile service for the user that clicked the button. Some SharePoint sites event support anonymous access - that's not going to work with DocuSign for sure. You need to double check the user that you used (typically System user for example will not have an email configured) has a valid email address. 
Also, you can find more information about our DocuSign for SharePoint 2013 (on prem) integration in this link - https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-for-sharepoint-2013.

We would be happy to help you resolve this issue but more information is needed and it's typically a good idea for you to work directly with us. Please email me at inbar.gazit@docusign.com so we can help you out. thanks!